# Python - Changing static variables

Tags: python

I am having trouble changing static variable of a class instead of just an instance.

Here is my code :

```
class GetAbsPath():

    config = RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    absPath = config['CSVPath']['Directory']

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getPath(cls):
        if cls.absPath.endswith('/'):
            pass
        else:
            cls.absPath += '/'
        return cls.absPath

    def setPath(cls, pathStr):
        cls.absPath = pathStr
```

In another class, I would have:

```
GetAbsPath.absPath = "some/other/path"
```

Therefore, I would want to change `absPath` variable in a way that `absPath` is permanently changed so that any other class getting the `absPath` would get`"some/other/path"`

Right now, `absPath`would always be the default value everytime I call `GetAbsPath.getPath()`.

Comment: Why do your instance methods have `cls` argument? `setPath` will replace `absPath` *only for the current instance*, after which it won't "see" changes to the class attribute. Should that be a class method?

Comment: Were `getPath` and `setPath` supposed to be class methods? They're not; they're instance methods, and `cls` is going to be just a funny name for `self`. Also, why do you have class variables for this? You're making a class just to manage one string global variable.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah they are suppose to be class methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decorate those methods with `@classmethod`.

**Edit** actually, I agree with user235712, you don't need a class here at all.